# Request timeout from pinging smtp.gmail.com

Tags: android, gmail, phpmailer, gmail-api

I have been working for this error for the whole day and already tried to search for help in many forums.

I have run my phpmailer code that used smtp.gmail.com, and for around 5 mins, the code does not response anything to the client.

So i tried to debug the smtp.gmail.com by pinging it in my cmd and i got this.

```
Pinging gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com [74.125.68.108] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
```

but when i tried typing telnet smtp.gmail.com 587 to cmd, it is connected

Comment: Strange. The IP address 74.125.68.108 isn't what I get when I use nslookup for smtp.gmail.com. Where are you getting that address from?

Comment: I am not sure, i just put ping smtp.gmail.com into my cmd.. and i get that ip address.
could i know what do u get? current i tried, i got 74.125.200.108

Comment: Put that IP address into nslookup - it doesn't seem to be anything to do with google.com

Comment: Check your host file. May be some malware set address smtp.gmail.com to malware IP

Comment: Fox - I also felt there are some malware, but how to check the host file?
Squonk- yeah, it is not connected to smtp.gmail.com

Comment: hosts file placement depends on your system: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29  Open it at any text editor and check names to IPs mapping

Comment: thanks  a lot for the answer, squonk and fox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`smtp.gmail.com` is not a fixed IP - it will map to many different IPs that change frequently - the TTL is only 5 minutes. You should not attempt to use the IP addresss directly, just look up the names.

There's no malware at work here. A reverse lookup points at `wq-in-f108.1e100.net`, and both that domain and the IP are owned by Google.

Ping doesn't necessarily always work - it can be blocked on outbound or inbound either by your ISP or Google, though that IP currently responds for me. If telnet to 587 works, then that's a better and more reliable test, since that's the service you actually want.